# SwiftData Modeling and saving non Nullable Relations

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    var schoolClass: SchoolClass

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button("add", action: {
                let schoolClassSubject = SchoolClassSubject(schoolClass: schoolClass)
                schoolClass.schoolClassSubjects.append(schoolClassSubject)
            })
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

@Model
class SchoolClass {
    var name: String
    var schoolClassSubjects: [SchoolClassSubject] = []
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
class SchoolClassSubject {
    var schoolClass: SchoolClass
    
    init(schoolClass: SchoolClass) {
        print("test")
        self.schoolClass = schoolClass
    }
}
```

`schoolClass` is already saved in swiftData and passed as a property to `ContentView`.

The line `let schoolClassSubject = SchoolClassSubject(schoolClass: schoolClass)` breaks with the following exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'schoolClass' between objects in different contexts (source = <NSManagedObject: 0x60000214cc30> (entity: SchoolClassSubject; id: 0x60000024ebe0 x-coredata:///SchoolClassSubject/t186670BB-357C-400C-8D6F-178BEB8F4B473; data: { schoolClass = nil; }) , destination = <NSManagedObject: 0x60000214cd70> (entity: SchoolClass; id: 0x600000276740 x-coredata:///SchoolClass/t186670BB-357C-400C-8D6F-178BEB8F4B472; data: { name = test; schoolClassSubjects = ( ); }))' *** First throw call

If I change my Model to this:

```
@Model
class SchoolClassSubject {
    var schoolClass: SchoolClass? = nil
    init() {
    }
}
```

And my saving code to this:

```
let schoolClassSubject = SchoolClassSubject()
modelContext.insert(schoolClassSubject)
schoolClassSubject.schoolClass = schoolClass
schoolClass.schoolClassSubjects.append(schoolClassSubject)
```

But I don't want to make `schoolClass` in `schoolClassSubject` optional as it is not in reality. How can I make it not optional and still save it without the given error?

Comment: Any luck on this? Same issue here, I have two models, one of which needs a non-optional (required) property of the other model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer was written using Xcode 15.0 beta 2, in future versions I assume this answer will become irrelevant and we can handle this more easily*

Once again, you must use the `@Relationship` annotation for the relationships to work properly and once you have that SwiftData will handle them for you.

And because of that you should not include any relationship properties in any `init` methods for your model.

So change the init in `SchoolClassSubject` to

```
init() {}
```

(I don't know if it is a bug that we need an empty init here or if this is just an odd case because there are no other properties)

And then change the code in the button action to

```
let schoolClassSubject = SchoolClassSubject()
modelContext.insert(schoolClassSubject)
schoolClassSubject.schoolClass = schoolClass
```

**To clarify the above code:**

- First create an instance of your model object
- Then insert the object into the model context
- Lastly assign any relationship properties to your object
- (save)

Comment: This only works for me if `schoolClass` in `schoolClassSubject` is optional. But i want it to be not optional as stated in the question.

Comment: I was using the exact same models as you have, nothing is optional.

Comment: I actually ran into the exact same problem with my own code today and the solution was exactly as stated in this answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson – How are you solving it on the latest beta (7)? As this doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: @Thecafremo Yes, looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76992387/swiftdata-inverse-relationship-stop-working-in-xcode-15-beta-7). I haven’t had time to look into it more than what is mentioned in the comments

Comment: @JoakimDanielson – I was hoping there would be a better solution. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
Think it depends on how to keep track of your RelationShip.
If One To Many Relation.

SchoolClass kan have many SchoolClassSubject
SchoolClassSubject only belong to one SchoolClass

@Model
class SchoolClass {
    var name: String
     @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
     var schoolClassSubjects =[SchoolClassSubject]() 
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
class SchoolClassSubject {
    var schoolClassSubject: String

    @Relationship(inverse: \SchoolClass.schoolClassSubjects)
    var schoolClass: SchoolClass?  // ? meaning of optional 


    init(schoolClassSubject: String) {
        //print("test")
        self.schoolClassSubject = schoolClassSubject
    }
}
// then in WindowGroup you have to have
 .modelContainer(for: SchoolClass .self

//In Views
 @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    let schoolClass: SchoolClass

// You can do in Views save func
let transaction = SchoolClassSubject(schoolClassSubject: "String here..")
```

transaction.schoolClass = schoolClass

Comment: It might be helpful to break this up into separate snippets so that code that belongs in a single file is grouped together and separated from other helpful lines of code.