# SwiftData inverse Relationship stop working in Xcode 15 beta 7

Tags: swift-data, xcode15

This approach works before Xcode 15 beta 7:

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(inverse:\Note.item) var notes: [Note]
    init(name: String = "Item name") {
        self.name = name
        self.notes = []
    }
}
@Model final class Note {
    var name: String
    var item: Item
    init(name: String = "Note name", item: Item) {
        self.name = name
        self.item = item
    }
}
@main
struct LifeKPIs_SwiftData_PlaygroundApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: [Item.self, Note.self])
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    var body: some View {
       //...
       let item = Item()
       modelContext.insert(item)
       //...
       let note = Note( item: item) //Error here
    }
}
```

> `Thread 1: "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'item' between objects in different contexts (source = <NSManagedObject: 0x6000021c3020> (entity: Note; id: 0x60000030ef00 <x-coredata:///Note/t0C99AC11-423B-4942-9B5D-C9F9E6A4370E7>; data: {\n    item = nil;\n    name = \"Note name\";\n}) , destination = <NSManagedObject: 0x60000212d400> (entity: Item; id: 0xabdd96b5daee1528 <x-coredata://4C4C1274-3F87-425E-837F-F2AEFD751084/Item/p1>; data: {\n    name = \"New Item 0\";\n    notes =     (\n    );\n}))"`

Comment: Making `Item` optional fixes the problem:  `var item: Item?`

Comment: Another variant I've seen in an Apple example project is `var item: Item!` which works if you don't want item to be optional but I guess you need to be extra careful when creating Note objects and always assign an Item to them directly

Comment: @quaternionboy doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Beta 8 is out. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: @HangarRash nope, still the same problem on Beta 8

Comment: It finally worked for me when I moved setters of relations in initialiser to the end after all other variables!

Comment: @YuriSidorov Would you mind posting your solution as an answer? I tried to implement your approach from your comment but couldn't get it work.

Comment: the error message indicates "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'item' between objects in different contexts" could it be how you are setting up your container and context? also like others have stated, make your `var item` optional