# Crash when sorting SwiftData Query with a SortDescriptor made from a KeyPath with an optional relationship in the chain

Tags: swift, swiftui, key, swift-data, swift-keypath

I have the following models:

```swift
@Model
class Game {
    var name: String
    var firstReleasedOn: Date?

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \QueueEntry.game)
    var queueEntry: QueueEntry?

    init(
        name: String,
        firstReleasedOn: Date?
    ) {
        self.name = name
        self.firstReleasedOn = firstReleasedOn
    }
}
```

```swift
@Model
public class QueueEntry {
    var game: Game?
    var createdOn: Date
    var order: Int

    init(order: Int) {
        self.createdOn = .now
        self.order = order
    }
}
```

I want to populate a `List` with all entries sorted by their game's release date, so I have the following:

```swift
struct QueueView: View {
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\QueueEntry.game?.firstReleasedOn)])
    private var entries: [LocalData.QueueEntry]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(entries) { entry in
            Text(entry.game.name ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code in Debug is totally fine. Running in Release, however, throws the following error:

> SwiftData/DataUtilities.swift:65: Fatal error: Couldn't find \QueueEntry.<computed 0x00000001049cd3e0 (Optional)>?.<computed 0x00000001049cd440 (Optional)> on QueueEntry with fields [SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "game", keypath: \QueueEntry.<computed 0x00000001049e3814 (Optional)>, defaultValue: nil, metadata: nil), SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "createdOn", keypath: \QueueEntry.<computed 0x00000001049e40e8 (Date)>, defaultValue: nil, metadata: nil), SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "order", keypath: \QueueEntry.<computed 0x00000001049e49ac (Int)>, defaultValue: nil, metadata: nil)]

`QueueEntry.game` needs to be optional since making it non-optional and trying to create the relationship in the init results in an `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reasoning explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597665/3791079) by [Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson).

Is this just a bug/issue with SwiftData that needs to be addressed by Apple? Is there some other workaround I can implement that maintains the integrity of the relatioship between `Game` and `QueueEntry`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now.. Did you find a solution, by any chance?

Comment: @SplittyDev Unfortunately not. I currently have a terrible ‘workaround’ in place where I’ve created a new `gameFirstReleasedOn` property on `QueueEntry`, and I assign the `Game.firstReleasedOn` date to that when I create new entry. Awful, and totally redundant data duplication, but I haven’t found anything better yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just saw it now.. I haven't found a fix either, I just went with querying everything and manually filtering and sorting it after.. Terrible for performance, but not much else I can do. I hope they fix it.

Comment: Exact same issue, also only on release. I’m also using a dedicated property combined with a `didSet`

Comment: Same for more. It's unfortunate as I'm having to manually perform the sorts now. Like Ben said, terrible for performance and very redundant... Weird it works fine on development builds. Boo!

Comment: Same experience with it only happening on release builds!